# Does calling random.normal on an array of values add noise?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I saw this pattern in someone's code:

```
import numpy as np
# Create array
xx = np.linspace(0.0, 100.0, num=100)
# Add Noise
xx = np.random.normal(xx)
```

and it seems to add some noise to each value of the array, but I can't find any documentation for this.  What's happening?  What determines the properties (i.e. scaling) of the noise?  Is the given value being treated as the mean (i.e. the `loc` parameter) of each sampling from the `normal` distribution?

I'd also be very curious to know why this behavior doesn't seem to be covered in the documentation.

Comment: It also works for the scale parameter, like np.random.normal(loc=np.zeros((4,4)),scale=np.array(range(1,17)).reshape((4,4)))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see it documented either, but many numpy functions that take an ndarray will [operate on it element-wise](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#). Anyway, you can easily verify that when passing it an array it call `numpy.random.normal` for each element on the array using that element's value as the mean and returns an array:

```
In [9]: xx = numpy.array([1, 10, 100, 1000])

In [10]: numpy.random.normal(xx)
Out[10]: 
array([  9.45865328e-01,   1.11542264e+01,   9.88601302e+01,
         1.00120448e+03])
```

It appears that it is using the default value of 1.0 for the scale. You can override this though:

```
In [12]: numpy.random.normal(xx, 10)
Out[12]: array([    8.92500743,    -5.66508088,    97.33440273,  1003.37940455])

In [13]: numpy.random.normal(xx, 100)
Out[13]: array([ -75.13092966,  -47.0841671 ,  154.12913986,  816.3126146 ])
```

Answer (score 1):

As a supplement to the above comments and example, the documentation is there in my implementation of numpy.
In abbreviated form, with large snips:

```
help(np.random.normal)
    normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=None)    
    Draw random samples from a normal (Gaussian) distribution.
    Parameters
    ----------
    loc : float    Mean ("centre") of the distribution.
    scale : float  Standard deviation (spread or "width") of the  
                   distribution.
    size : tuple of ints,   Output shape.
           If the given shape is, e.g., ``(m, n, k)``, then
           ``m * n * k`` samples are drawn.
```

If you wish to produce a number of data values with a particular shape, centered about a mean with a specified standard deviation, you could do the following.

```
>>> x = 10
>>> vals = np.random.normal(x,3.,(10,))
>>> vals
array([ 10.6999745 ,   9.58139692,  14.04490407,   9.54797132,
        10.18378835,  11.42772729,   5.22100578,   9.51757533,
        12.95314676,  13.77068901])
```

which generates an array of 10 values, shape (10,) with a mean of 10 and values spread within +/- 3 std deviations.  The actual distribution function, references and a matplotlib code sample are also provided.
I am using np.version.version '1.8.0'.

This is a useful function should you want to produce point samples (X,Y) centered about a mean value with a known spread.